# Можно ли преобразовать массив с числами в массив байт для кодирования аудио в javascript

Tags: javascript, web-audio

Есть массив с int числами, например `[1,16, 170, 5,7, 110, 200, 23, 70]` можно ли его как-то преобразовать посредством javascript, чтоб воспроизвести через Web Audio API?

Comment: Почему бы вам не почитать [Web Audio API](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API) внимательнее, и не найти там  например [это](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/AudioContext/createBuffer)

Comment: Поня, сейчас посмотрю, спасибо!

Comment: Вопрос закрыт спасибо nick_n_a